# Setup File .env in Slim Framework

Tags: php, slim, phpdotenv

I'm new to slim framework. I'd try to add .env file in root folder project and then I want to access the value inside .env file. I've tried use this package https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv and load .env in index.php. But when I tried to get the value in .env file use like ex: getenv("DB_NAME") it returns false. Not return string value of DB_NAME.

.env

```
DB_HOST = localhost
DB_PORT = 3306
DB_NAME = DB
DB_USER = root
DB_PASSWORD =
```

index.php

```
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

I use slim framework ^4.*, web server laravel valet, database MySQL. Or is there any other alternative way to configure .env in slim framework ? Thank You.

Comment: remove spacing ` = `

Comment: I tried. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [package readme file](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#putenv-and-getenv):

> Using getenv() and putenv() is strongly discouraged due to the fact
> that these functions are not thread safe, however it is still possible
> to instruct PHP dotenv to use these functions. **Instead of calling
> `Dotenv::createImmutable`, one can call
> `Dotenv::createUnsafeImmutable`**, which will add the PutenvAdapter
> behind the scenes. **Your environment variables will now be available
> using the getenv method, as well as the super-globals.**

So the main method of getting these values is using `$_ENV` and `$_SERVER` super-global not `getenv()` function.

You should either try to retrieve the values like:

```php
$db_name = $_ENV['DB_NAME'];
```

or load the .env file like the example provided in the package:

```php
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createUnsafeImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

Also, make sure you pass correct directory (the one that .env file resides in) as the parameter. That normally should not be in the same directory as **index.php** but the example code you provide implies you are putting both files in one directory.

Comment: Do u know what does "not thread safe" mean?